# SSIS: How to skip rows during import?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

in 2000 I could do this DTSTransformStat_OK.  Is there an equivalent of this in BIDS 2008?

Comment: Or perhaps if anyone could translate this: main=DTSTransformStat_OK

Answer (score 7):

You may find something better in SSIS.  In the Data Flow task, you can use a Conditional Split component.  In the Conditional Split, you can create condition(s) and pass rows to different outputs based on the condition.  You can also ignore, or discard, rows that don't meet the conditions.

If you must use a Script Component in the data flow, you can look at asynchronous inputs/outputs.  By default the Script Component is synchronous, which means for each row that enters the Script Component, one row exits.  When you set the Script Component to asynchronous, your script code is responsible for controlling the rows and columns that exit the script.  So, you can use your conditions in the script to determine which rows are skipped.

For an asynchronous Script Component, create a new Script Component as a transformation.  Edit the component and select the Inputs and Outputs tab.  Select the Output 0 branch and alter the SynchronousInputID property to None.  Expand the treeview under the Output 0 branch and add the list of columns that will define the output row.  Then, start writing your script.